# String android.content.Context.getPackageName

Tags: android, android-room

Hi I have a problem with click on the cardview, in practice since I added a searchview on the toolbar to search for items on the list I create, selecting an object in the list does not allow me to go to change parameters through the edit class

you would be so kind as to help me solve this problem and help me understand where I'm wrong

RoomAdapter

```
  public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.TicketHolder> implements Filterable {
       //List<TicketEntity> ticketEntity = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<TicketEntity> ticketEntity;
        private List<TicketEntity> ticketEntitySearch;
        private Context mCtx;

        public RoomAdapter(List<TicketEntity> ticketEntity){
            this.ticketEntity = ticketEntity;
          // this.mCtx = mCtx;
            ticketEntitySearch = new ArrayList<>(ticketEntity);
        }

        @Override
        public TicketHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_recyclerview, parent, false);
            return new TicketHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TicketHolder holder, int position) {
            TicketEntity currenTicket = ticketEntity.get(position);
            holder.mTextticket.setText(currenTicket.getNumticket());
            holder.mTextredattore.setText(currenTicket.getRedattore());
            holder.mTexttarga.setText(currenTicket.getTarga());
            holder.mTextdataA.setText(currenTicket.getDopen());
            holder.mTextmanutenzioneG.setText(currenTicket.getMateriale());
            holder.mTextdataC.setText(currenTicket.getDclosed());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return ticketEntity.size();
        }

        public void setTicketEntity(List<TicketEntity> ticketEntity){
            this.ticketEntity = ticketEntity;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        void setTickets(List<TicketEntity> tickets){
            ticketEntity = tickets;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return ticketFilter;
        }
        private Filter ticketFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                List<TicketEntity>filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    filteredList.addAll(ticketEntitySearch);
                }else{
                    String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                    for (TicketEntity item : ticketEntitySearch){
                        if(item.getNumticket().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                            filteredList.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredList;
                return  results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                ticketEntity.clear();
                ticketEntity.addAll((List)results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };

        class TicketHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

            TextView mTextticket,mTextredattore,mTexttarga,mTextdataA,mTextmanutenzioneG,mTextdataC;
            Context mCtx;
            //todo Costructor
            public TicketHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                mTextticket = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_ticket);
                mTextredattore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_redattore);
                mTexttarga = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_targa);
                mTextdataA = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_dataA);
                mTextmanutenzioneG = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_materiale);
                mTextdataC = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_dataC);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TicketEntity ticket = ticketEntity.get(getAdapterPosition());
                Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx,ModificaActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ticket", ticket);
                mCtx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        /*public TicketEntity getTicketSwipe(int position){
            return ticketEntity.get(position);
        }
    */

    }
```

Visualizza

```
package alessandro.mystudio.ticketfirebase;
public class Visualizza extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
Toolbar mToolbar;
List<TicketEntity> tickets;
RoomAdapter adapter;
private AppDatabase appDatabase;
private Context mCtx;
//private static final String TAG = "Visualizza";
//public static final int ADD_TICKET_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview);

    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarLayout);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this);
    BuildRecyclearView();
    new getAll().execute();
    new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);

}

//TODO METODO DI SWIPE  DELETE SULLA CARDVIEW
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)
{
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        if(tickets !=null){
            TicketEntity swipedTicket = tickets.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            if(swipedTicket != null){
                swipeToDelete(swipedTicket, viewHolder);
            }

        }
    }
};

//TODO MESSAGGIO ALERT DIALOG DI CONFERMA OPPURE DI ANNULLARE
private void swipeToDelete( final TicketEntity swipedTicket, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(Visualizza.this)
            .setMessage("Delete Ticket?")
            .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // TODO: 28/09/2018 delete note
                    // Item swiped.
                    int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                    // Remove from database
                    new deleteTicket(pos).execute(tickets.get(pos));
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // TODO: 28/09/2018  Undo swipe and restore swipedNote
                    mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create().show();
}

//TODO Costruzione della RecyclerView
public void BuildRecyclearView() {
    //todo dichiarazione adapter e chiamiamo il suo costruttore passandogli i parametri necessari
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.miorecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

//TODO VISUALIZZARE TUTTI I TICKET
private class getAll extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        tickets = (List<TicketEntity>) appDatabase.ticketDao().getAll();
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        adapter = new RoomAdapter(tickets);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}


//TODO MESSAGGIO DI ALERDIALOG
public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}


//TODO Procedura ToolBar Menu & SearchView
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    //searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}


//TODO DELETE TICKET
private class deleteTicket extends AsyncTask<TicketEntity, Void, Void>
{
    int pos;
    public deleteTicket(int pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(TicketEntity... ticketEntities) {
        appDatabase.ticketDao().deleteTicket(ticketEntities[0].getId());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        tickets.remove(pos);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
         }
    }


}
```

Comment: beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: alessandro.mystudio.ticketfirebase, PID: 2448
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4868)
        at alessandro.mystudio.ticketfirebase.Room.RoomAdapter$TicketHolder.onClick(RoomAdapter.java:118)

Comment: I forgot he wrote error which visualized me